# How to check if a sharepoint page from Page Library is published major using sharepoint designer workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity, workflow-designer

Basically, i need to initiate a task process after the page is published. Is there are way to check if the page is published major using sharepoint designer workflow ?

I have the concept of using regular expression "\d.0" (which checks major version). But, sometimes it is not working. Anyone has any other options/solutions for this ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use rest web api in sharepoint 2013 workflow platform. use below rest url and get level of file

> http://siteurl/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('Serverrelativeurl')?$select=Level

in json return please check level

> if Level: Gets a value that specifies the publishing level of the
>   file. Represents an SP.FileLevel value: Published = 1; Draft = 2;
>   Checkout = 255.

if it is solving your problem please mark this as answer.